# Jersey JAX-RS Client XML to java.util.List deserialization

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to access a JAX-RS Service (jersey implementation) which is returning me a java.util.list of Employees in XML format.

The Service method signature looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/getEmployeeListXML")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<EmployeeXML> getEmployeeListXML(@QueryParam("id") String id){
    //Some code which returns a List<EmployeeXML>
}
```

The format of the XML returned is like this:

```
<employeeXMLs>
    <employeeXML>
            <empId>1</empId>
            <empName>John</empName>
            <empAge>35</empAge>
            <empSex>Male</empSex>
    </employeeXML>
    <employeeXML>
            <empId>2</empId>
            <empName>Lisa</empName>
            <empAge>23</empAge>
            <empSex>Female</empSex>
    </employeeXML>
</employeeXMLs>
```

For accessing this from my jersey Client, I am using this code:

```
List<EmployeeXML> empListXML = (List<EmployeeXML>)service.path("rest").path("GetService").path("getEmployeeListXML").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(EmployeeXML.class);
```

This is not correct since the return type should be a list but in the get method, presently I am trying to retrieve a single object. I am not sure how to retrieve the List from the client here :(

I am getting this exception:

```
 unexpected element (uri:"", local:"employeeXMLs"). Expected elements are <{}employeeListXML>,<{}employeeXML>
```

Please help me out to make this work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a 'supertype token' to define the return type in your client class:

```
List<EmployeeXML> empListXML = service
    .path("rest")
    .path("GetService")
    .path("getEmployeeListXML")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .get(new GenericType<List<EmployeeXML>>() {});
```

The supertype token is required in order to 'retain' generic parameter information that Jersey will use when deserializing the server response.

Comment: Thanks for the immidiate reply :) I have to remove the .getType() from the end, otherwise I am getting a compilation error `The method get(Class<T>) in the type WebResource.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (Type)`.

Comment: @WhoAmI - yes, the `getType()` is not needed, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `GenericType` class to fetch a list of objects:

```
List<EmployeeXML> empListXML = (List<EmployeeXML>)service.path("rest").path("GetService").path("getEmployeeListXML").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(new GenericType<List<EmployeeXML>>(){});
```

Comment: I can't imagine you did not see my answer when you posted this. Wow.

Comment: @Perception Believe it or not, but I have my own brain. I don't need to copy someone.